# How to programatically (VBA/NetOffice) insert an Bitmap Excel Object?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I have the requirement to create an Bitmap Object from a Excel Path inside a ms-word document, and I can't seem to find a way to do it in one step.

The current solution is the following.

1. Create a Field Object
2. Unlink the Field Object

Like this:

```
Dim fld As Field
Set fld = Selection.Fields.Add(Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldLink, "Excel.Sheet.12 ""[Path to Xlsx]"" ""[Sheet+Range]"" \b", False)
fld.Update
fld.Unlink
```

- `\b` says the field should represented as a Bitmap object.
- With `fld.Unlink` I am dropping the link and the Bitmap stays.

Is there a way to directly create the Bitmap Object (InlineShape) without the field approach?

I tried to record a macro in ms-word to see how ms-word is doing it but saddly it only gives:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteBitmap, Placement:= wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

If possible I would like to avoid working with Clipboard and PasteSpecial.

**Edit:**

Since the given answer has shown me that my question wasn't as clear as I hoped it to be.

So first of all, the only Information I currently have are

1. The path to an XLSX file
2. The Sheet and Range of said XLSX File

eg. 
C:\test\myWorkbook.xlsx
Sheet1!A1:D10

Thats all the Information I have.
With this Information I need to programatically create a Bitmap inside my ms-word document.

As shown above I already have a solution which does exactly this, by doing a LINK to the said XLSX file and after it got updated dropping that link to only have the Bitmap left.
A Bitmap is staying here because of the `\b` flag which tells the LINK to produce a Bitmap, instead of a RTF/HTML.

My question now is, if there is another way I am currently doing it.

The current answer, does indeed insert a Bitmap into my ms-word document, but where do I get the Bitmap from, as the answer isn't aware of the fact that I need an image of an excel workbook? As I said earlier, I only have limited information and no Bitmap.

What I want to achieve can be done without programatically by using the Paste Special functionality
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/paste-special-e03db6c7-8295-4529-957d-16ac8a778719

1. Open Xlsx/Docx
2. Copy Cells from Xlsx
3. Go to Docx
4. Use Paste Special
5. Select Bitmap
6. Hit OK

The output you receive in your Docx is what I desire to make programatically, without Clipboard and Paste Special and with a, if possible, better solution than I currently have.

Comment: I'd say there isn't any better approach than creating a field code and unlinking it, as you're currently doing. Consider: Any other method would involve opening the Excel workbook, which is resource intensive. Then you'd essentially have to create a screen shot to get the bitmap - Word is taking care of this for you, as well. A traditional screen shot is put on the Clipboard, which you want to avoid, anyway... Excel can save "things" to graphics files (as I recall, anyway) but that means saving a file to disk, which you apparently don't want, either.

Comment: *Theoretically* the only other possibility is to use the Open XML file formats to extract the *exact content* required from an Excel workbook, recreate it in Word (either in the closed or open file) as an "OLE Object", which would then need to be converted to a static graphic (in essence, unlinking the field code). Any approach is going to be a lot more work, a lot more code, a lot more steps and a lot more resource-intensive than what you have...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
string fileName = "c://msdn.bmp";  //the picture file to be inserted
Object oMissed = doc.Paragraphs[2].Range; //the position you want to insert
Object oLinkToFile = false;  //default
Object oSaveWithDocument = true;//default
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fieldName, ref  oLinkToFile, ref  oSaveWithDocument, ref  oMissed);
```

See [insert a picture into a word document using c#?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/de-DE/5d68fa72-3fd2-49ca-bf4b-dce4c2899839/insert-a-picture-into-a-word-document-using-c?forum=vsto) for more information.

Comment: Thx, but I don't have a Bitmap file - the Bitmap is created on the fly by word (or excel) when I am adding a excel link to word. - like this: https://spreadsheeto.com/excel-to-word/ just instead of an "Excel Work Sheet" Object I need it to be "Bitmap" - and I wouldn't know of a way to transform the excel path + sheet + range information into a Bitmap by myself

Comment: You can save the result bitmap as a file on the disk and then add it as the code shows. Or you can use the `PasteSpecial` method. It is up to you which way is to choose.

Comment: But how would I get the `result bitmap`? As I tried to explain I am not doing the `Bitmap` myself word/excel does it while creating the field

Comment: The question is: How to programatically (VBA/NetOffice) insert an Bitmap Excel Object?

Comment: I'd recommend posting a separate question then.

Comment: Sorry but I believe you are missing the point as my question says an "Bitmap Excel Object", so Excel related Bitmap, your answer is ignoring the "Excel" part in my question and only explains how to insert a Bitmap. If I am wrong, please help me to understand your answer better. Updated my quesiton.

Comment: Are you going to change the post each time? Thankfully, you didn't change the subject.

Comment: I will ignore the question, since I am getting sarcasm/rude vibes, thx for your time so far. (hope I am correct with my assumption)